# Combinations with un-fixed choices

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I just started using Python for this project I was working on. I created a List of lists of lists of integers.
Ex. `[[[0,1,2],[0,2,1]],[[0,1,2],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,2],[1,0,2]]]`. I want to make all possible arrays that take one list from each list in the large list and map the integers to the corresponding columns on the 2d array. How can I do that without nested for loops? I would have used for loops for each list of lists, but the lengths of the list aren't fixed. The list follows this pattern.

`list ((l[i])[(i-1)!])[i]`
ex of final matrix.

```
[0  2  1]   
[2  1  0]         
[1  0  2]
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
k = (range(len(m)))
q = list(permutations(k))
p = list
for e in range(0, len(m)):
    p.extend(q)
    for j in range(0, len(m)):
        if ((p[e])[j])[e] != e:
            p[e].pop(j)
for z in range(0, len(m)):
```

Where m is the array I want to create (len(m) x len(m) array)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could show what code you have written so far, or at the very least explain what `list ((l[i])[(i-1)!])[i]` means (since it isn't valid python).

Comment: I was trying to show the number of values in each list. If there are I lists of lists, there are (i-1)! lists in each list of lists, and i integers in each list.